# where to store alias for terraform for particular workspace in vscode?

Tags: bash, terraform, alias

I have a separate folder "terraform_lab2" where i run my terraform scripts.
I'd like to have terraform aliased to "t" or "ter" whenever i startup only that specific workspace in vscode.

I tried to create temp alias, typed in intergrated bash terminal:

```
alias terraform=ter
```

but it's not working. How to make it work in this specific project folder/vscode workspace?

Comment: Consider using an exported function instead of an alias. Exported functions, as the name implies, are _exported_ through the environment, so all subprocesses inheriting the relevant environment variables can pick them up. (In your case: `terraform() { ter "$@"; }; export -f terraform` will make `terraform` call `ter`, not just in the current shell but also in copies of bash started in subshells).

Comment: ...as for "only this particular workspace", one of the advantages functions have over aliases is that you can put conditional logic in them, so you can make the function check its current working directory, or what process started it, or for the presence of an environment variable you have VS code set to export, or so forth as appropriate.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this (configure alias for specific VSCode workspace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this to .bashrc

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ "$bashrc" != "$PWD" && "$PWD" != "$HOME" && -e .bashrc ]]; then bashrc="$PWD"; . .bashrc; fi'
```

for windows, follow this link
https://wahlnetwork.com/2020/07/07/windows-aliases-for-terraform-and-git/